# is there still any way to get original css stylesheet property value which is NOT computed after chrome 64?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am wondering if there is still any way to access stylesheet property value after javascript .stylesheets.cssRules seems been banned by chrome 64.(?)

my question is simple...here is my code demo.

how can i still get the original font-size value of .a as "2vw" but not "100px"?

```js
$(function(){
$('.a').css('font-size','100px');
})
```

```css
.a{
font-size:2vw;
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">font size: 12px</div>
```

Comment: That is not banned; it just respects the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: so it's not banned ? so how can i still use .cssRule?

Comment: Yes; that property still works fine.  Read the answer to that question.

Comment: I think I got that... just duplicated all the content of style.css into <style></style> and my code is working now, thank you :D